# 'Could not find the main class error' in a build file

Tags: java, apache, ant

I have craated a Java application with an Ant build file containing the jar-task task that generate a jar file from the application.

```
<target name="jar-task" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
    <jar destfile="jar/guix.jar" basedir="${bin.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}">
            <include name="${basedir}/images/**/" />
            </fileset>
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="IO.Deep.clk.GUI"/>
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${basedir}/SPLASH-2.0.0.jar ${basedir}/lib/dist/* ${basedir}/user.properties"/>
            </manifest>
        <filelist dir="${basedir}" files="user.properties"/>
    </jar>
</target>
```

When I execute on the command line however a NoClassDefFoundError stating

```
Could not find the main class IO.Deep.clk.GUI. Program will exit.
```

Now, the GUI file is exactly in the specific folder and in the same package, I really can't understand where the error may be...can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

The name `images` suggests, that the jar file will contain only images. But where is the actual code?

> ```
>     <fileset dir="${basedir}">
>         <include name="${basedir}/images/**/" />
>     </fileset>
> ```

This piece

> ```
>     <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${basedir}/SPLASH-2.0.0.jar ${basedir}/lib/dist/* ${basedir}/user.properties"/>
> ```

will write full qualified pathnames into the manifest. Are sure, that this is correct? Also note, that the code will not find `user.properties` by putting the file on the classpath. The classpath can contain only directories or jar-files in which classes or other stuff will be searched for. But simple files won't work.

I'm also not sure about the `lib/*` part. Is the class `IO.Deep.clk.GUI` in one of the jar files in that directory? That would be a hint, that all directories must be listed explicitly. If that's not a problem - good.

**EDIT**: 
The classpath problems can be avoided by adding the task `manifestclasspath` ([Ant docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/manifestclasspath.html)) before the call of `jar` and by using the generated classpath value inside the `manifest` attribute. Outline:

```
    <manifestclasspath property="jar.class.path" jarfile="jar/guix.jar">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="." includes="*.jar" />
            <fileset dir="." includes="lib/*.jar" />
        </classpath>
    </manifestclasspath>
    <echo message="Class-Path will be: ${jar.class.path}" />
    <jar ....>
        ....
        <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${jar.class.path}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your resulting filest inside the jar task contains all the files you need?

For debugging you can use a path convert to the fileset out of the jar task and echo it so that you can verfiy that you have the correct files. If this is OK then I don't see something else wrong in your file although I have limited experience with the jar task myself.