# Recursively including jars into the classpath

Tags: java, ant

I have a project with several third-party JAR files in several directories.  Currently, the project uses some ant tricks to recursively include all jar files into the classpath.   I want to build a deployment for another site which will include JAR'ing my own code into a single file and somehow including the other JARs that I need.  [Oracle claims](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) that wildcards on the commandline will not recursively include jars.  I want the deployment to work in Windows or Linux.

It seems like I have the following options:

1. Include ant with my JAR and run the existing script.
2. Somehow re-organize the jars to be in a single directory so I can use a wildcard in my classpath.  Hopefully it won't break the third-party libraries.
3. Manually create a big, ugly classpath.

Does anyone know of an easier way?  I'm inclined to go with #1 for now.

Comment: You can put the jars in one directory and include a script that builds the classpath.

Comment: If a jar has a dependency on where it's located, that jar is broken--I've certainly never seen such a thing.

Comment: @Dave Newton it's a feature of the jar manifest, see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

Comment: @Matt He still needs to enumerate the list of jars in the master jar.

Comment: @Jagat edited to clarify, I was responding to the "the jar is broken" comment

Comment: @Matt And I'm saying if a *library* has a dependency on where it's located, that library is broken and a bad citizen.

Comment: @DaveNewton the OP's Q suggests it is an app not a library, for which relative paths are pretty common practice

Comment: @Matt His concern was to not break the third-party libraries. If a third-party library breaks because of where it's located, it's broken. OP is building a deployable package and needs to include those libraries on the classpath. If those libraries break because of their location, those libraries are broken.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with #2.  When you build your distribution, copy all the jars to a "lib" directory, then include them all using wildcards.  I've never known a third party library to break when doing such a thing. 
 There shouldn't be much trickery to it using ant: use copy with flatten="true" and include the fileset(s) indicating the directories/jars to recurse through.

Answer (score 0):

option 4: The goal is to make you app startable simply with

```
java -jar your.jar
```

The main class and the classpath are set in the `MANIFEST.MF` of `your.jar`. Use ant to create the classpath at build time. This can be either a big, ugly, nested tree or a big, ugly flattened tree in `lib`.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858766/generate-manifest-class-path-from-classpath-in-ant), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693240/could-not-find-the-main-class-error-in-a-build-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690213/executing-a-java-running-application-from-a-jar-or-batch-file) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JarJar](https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/) and put everything in a single JAR file. You'll need to verify third-party licensing and distribution terms to ensure you can repackage their libraries.